# How to dynamically bind the List<Object> to picker in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to bind the List to a picker control in Xamarin forms. But I'm not able to get the picker populated.

Please let me know what I'm missing here.

```
[PropertyChanged.AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class TransactionFilterViewModel : TransactionListViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePicker { get; set; }

    //public ObservableCollection<GroupedFilterModel> TransactionFilters { get; set; }
    List<string> FilterTypes = new List<string>() { "TRANSACTION TYPE", "BENEFIT TYPE", "DATE RANGE" };

    public List<TransactionBenefitViewModel> TransactionBenefits { get; set; }

    public TransactionType TransactionTypeFilter { get; set; }

    public string BenefitTypeFilter { get; set; }

    public DateTime FromDateFilter { get; set; }

    public DateTime ToDateFilter { get; set; }

    public List<Benefit> Benefits = new List<Benefit>();

    //public List<string> lstbenefits = new List<string>() { "manju", "vinu", "jaggu" };

    private TransactionBenefitViewModel _selectedBenefit;

    public TransactionBenefitViewModel SelectedBenefit { 
        get
        {
            return _selectedBenefit;
        } 
        set{
            if(value != null){
                SelectedBenefit = _selectedBenefit;
            }
        } 
    }

    public override void Init()
    {
        base.Init();

        Title = "Filter";

        FromDateFilter = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(Constants.TransactionsDefaultMonthsFrom);
        ToDateFilter = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public TransactionFilterViewModel(){
        TransactionBenefits = new List<TransactionBenefitViewModel>();
        GetBenefits();
    }

    private void GetBenefits(){
        Benefits = employeeService.GetBenefits(App.User.Account, 6);
        TransactionBenefitViewModel transactionBenefitViewModel = new TransactionBenefitViewModel();
        transactionBenefitViewModel.BenefitName = "All";
        transactionBenefitViewModel.IsSelected = true;
        transactionBenefitViewModel.BenefitSelected = null;
        TransactionBenefits.Add(transactionBenefitViewModel);

        foreach (Benefit item in Benefits){
            transactionBenefitViewModel = new TransactionBenefitViewModel();
            transactionBenefitViewModel.BenefitName = item.Name;
            transactionBenefitViewModel.IsSelected = false;
            transactionBenefitViewModel.BenefitSelected = item;
            TransactionBenefits.Add(transactionBenefitViewModel);

        }

    }

}
public class TransactionBenefitViewModel{
    public Benefit BenefitSelected { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public string BenefitName { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:BasePage Title="{Binding Title}" 
        x:TypeArguments="vm:TransactionFilterViewModel" 
        xmlns:p="clr-    namespace:MMSG.Mobile.ContentPages;assembly=MMSG.Mobile;"
        xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MMSG.Mobile.Converters" 
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MMSG.Mobile.ViewModels;assembly=MMSG.Mobile;" 
        xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
        x:Class="MMSG.Mobile.ContentPages.TransactionFilterPage" 
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MMSG.Mobile.CustomControls"
        xmlns:effects="clr-namespace:MMSG.Mobile.Effects"
        xmlns:cells="clr-namespace:MMSG.Mobile.Views.Cells" 
        xmlns:repeater="clr-namespace:XamarinForms.Plugin.Repeater;assembly=MMSG.Mobile"
        xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:MMSG.Mobile.Behaviors">
<ContentView.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="primaryBackgroundColor">#EFEFF4</Color>
        <Color x:Key="whiteBackgroundColor">#FFFFFF</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ErrorColor">#e40039</Color>
        <Style x:Key="layoutTitle" TargetType="StackLayout">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15,12.5">
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="layoutSpacingPrimary" TargetType="StackLayout">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15">
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="labelTitle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#6D6D72">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Font" Value="13">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="15">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalTextAlignment" Value="Center">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand">
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="labelTitleBold" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#6D6D72">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Font" Value="Bold,13">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="15">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalTextAlignment" Value="Center">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand">
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="separator" TargetType="BoxView">
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="1">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#bbbbbb">
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="layoutListItem" TargetType="StackLayout">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15, 12">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="labelStandard" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Font" Value="17">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#030303">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="20">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalTextAlignment" Value="Center">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand">
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="imgListItem" TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="16">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="End">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center">
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="labelLink" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Font" Value="17">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#0076FF">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="MinimumHeightRequest" Value="20">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalTextAlignment" Value="Center">
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="labelErrorSummary" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Font" Value="17">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource ErrorColor}">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="20">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalTextAlignment" Value="Center">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15,8">
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="StackLayout">
            <Setter Property="Spacing" Value="0">
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentView.Resources>
<p:BasePage.Content BackgroundColor="#EFEFF4">
    <ScrollView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource primaryBackgroundColor}">
        <BoxView Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Style="{StaticResource layoutTitle}">
            <Label Text="TRANSACTION TYPE" Style="{StaticResource labelTitle}">
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <BoxView Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>

        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{StaticResource whiteBackgroundColor}">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="15,0,0,0" > 
            <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource layoutListItem}">
                <Label Text="tttt" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                <Image Source="checkmark.png" HorizontalOptions="End" />
            </StackLayout>
            <BoxView Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>
        </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{StaticResource whiteBackgroundColor}">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="15,0,0,0" > 
            <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource layoutListItem}">
                <Label Text="tttt" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                <Image Source="checkmark.png" HorizontalOptions="End" />
            </StackLayout>
            <BoxView Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>
        </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{StaticResource whiteBackgroundColor}">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="15,0,0,0" > 
            <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource layoutListItem}">
                <Label Text="tttt" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                <Image Source="checkmark.png" HorizontalOptions="End" />
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>

        <BoxView Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Style="{StaticResource layoutTitle}">
            <Label Text="BENEFIT TYPE" Style="{StaticResource labelTitle}">
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <BoxView Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF">
            <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource layoutListItem}">
                <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding TransactionBenefits}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding BenefitName}">
                    <Picker.Effects>
                        <effects:EntryNoBorderEffect />
                    </Picker.Effects>
                </Picker>
                <Image Source="arrow_list.png" Style="{StaticResource imgListItem}">
                </Image>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>

        <BoxView Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Style="{StaticResource layoutTitle}">
            <Label Text="DATE RANGE" Style="{StaticResource labelTitle}">
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <BoxView Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>

        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{StaticResource whiteBackgroundColor}">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="15,0,0,0"> 
                <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource layoutListItem}">
                    <Label Text="From" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                    <DatePicker Date="{Binding FromDateFilter}" TextColor="#777777" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="End">
                        <DatePicker.Format>dd-MMMM-yyyy</DatePicker.Format>
                        <DatePicker.Effects>
                            <effects:EntryNoBorderEffect />
                        </DatePicker.Effects>
                    </DatePicker>
                </StackLayout>
                <BoxView Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="15,0,0,0"> 
                <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource layoutListItem}">
                    <Label Text="To" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                    <DatePicker Date="{Binding ToDateFilter}" TextColor="#777777" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="End">
                        <DatePicker.Format>dd-MMMM-yyyy</DatePicker.Format>
                        <DatePicker.Effects>
                            <effects:EntryNoBorderEffect />
                        </DatePicker.Effects>
                    </DatePicker>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
        <BoxView Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Style="{StaticResource layoutSpacingPrimary}">
            <Button Text="Apply" BackgroundColor="#007AFF" TextColor="White"  />
            <Button Text="Clear Filters"  />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
</p:BasePage.Content>
```

My view model is TransactionFilterViewModel which is bound to the XAML view TransactionFilterPage. Could you please let me know why am I not able to bind the picker

Comment: None of your properties appear to trigger the `PropertyChanged` event...

Answer (score 0):

first, `TransactionBenefits` needs to be a *public property*

```
public class BenefitsViewModel{
    public List<TransactionBenefitViewModel> TransactionBenefits  { get; set; }
```

then in your XAML, `ItemsSource` is the `IEnumerable` that populates the picker, while `ItemDisplayBinding` is the property to display in the picker UI

```
<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding TransactionBenefits}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding BenefitName}">
```

Ref: [Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have updated the my query as suggested. but still it is not working

Comment: "Not working" does not tell me anything.  Is it displaying any entries?  Or is it displaying the wrong values?  Are you sure that TransactionBenefits contains data?  Do you have the BindingContext set correctly?

Comment: have updated the entire view model and the XAML file. Could you please let me know why the dropdown might not be getting populated. I'm able to get the required data from the service, which I'm binding to the property

Comment: you may need to manually raise a PropertyChanged event after you get your data